# Erro ao incluir composer (Class not found)

Tags: php, composer

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Class 'wkhtmltopdf\Pdf' not found in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/common/class/PrePagoConsulta.php
>   on line 480

Trecho do código:

```
use wkhtmltopdf\Pdf;

class PrePagoConsulta extends Query
{
    public function gerarPDF($html, $nomeArquivo){

        $pdf = new Pdf($html); // * Linha 480

        if (!$pdf->saveAs($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/consultas-pre/'.$nomeArquivo.'.pdf')) {
            echo $pdf->getError();
        }
    }
}
```

E a estrutura de pastas está da seguinte maneira:

[image: Estrutura de classes]

No **autoload_psr4.php**, estou setando da seguinte maneira:

```
return array(
    'wkhtmltopdf\\' => array($vendorDir.'/wkhtmltopdf/src')
);
```

Como posso corrigir o erro? Onde estou errando? hehe

Comment: Como esta o eu composer.json?

Comment: ve como tá o composer.lock

Answer (score 2):

Esse esquema esta estranho, porque quando instala fica na pasta `vendor`, a não ser que você tenha configurado para `lib`, esta me parecendo que você não usou o composer para instalar os pacotes, mas sim tentou instalar manualmente.

Se o pacote que você esta usando for o https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf, então você instalou algo errado, porque o nome do pacote não é `wkhtmltopdf`, mas sim `phpwkhtmltopdf` (prefixado 
"`php`"), logo o correto deveria ser:

```
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;

class PrePagoConsulta extends Query
{
    public function gerarPDF($html, $nomeArquivo){

        $pdf = new Pdf($html); // * Linha 480

        if (!$pdf->saveAs($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/upload/consultas-pre/'.$nomeArquivo.'.pdf')) {
            echo $pdf->getError();
        }
    }
}
```

No entanto se você instalou manualmente eu realmente recomendo que você reveja isso e tente instalar via linha de comando (que é justamente o que o composer faz), faça algo como:

```
cd pastadomeuprojeto
composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf
```

Pronto ele fará tudo manualmente, então importe:

```
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;
```

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento foi instalado manualmente mesmo. Ainda não me dei com o composer. Gostaria que essas libs fossem instaladas dentro da pasta /common/libs... Já tentei fazer a instalação, mas sempre dá problema... veja:

https://i.imgur.com/8Vreuyw.png

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tentei usando php na frente do composer, e sem também.

Comment: Não consigo instalar esta dependência manualmente então? bom... vou dar uma lida a respeito então.

Comment: @MaykelEsser conseguir consegue, mas é problemático, complicado e vai mais dar problema de entender as coisas do que fazer pelas vias comuns, tipo uma nova atualização no pacote especifico irá auto ajustar a maior parte das coisas sem vc precisar mexer em nada

Comment: Entendo. Até tentei usar composer diversas vezes, mas sempre tenho esse problema de command not found, sendo que estou usando no diretório em que está listado o composer.phar...

Comment: mas aí o problema é outro! Vou tentar aqui!

Comment: @MaykelEsser é linux ou windows?

Comment: osx! Consegui que o composer.phar baixe no diretório que gostaria, mas não consigo executar nenhum comando nele... sempre dá "command not found"!